# syntax error : 'source' (source) is not valid input at this position

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-1064

I'm  new to mysql. i'm trying to install employees sample database

I tried few as mentioned in stackoverflow but it didn't help

can any one please tell me how to solve this

```
SELECT 'LOADING departments' as 'INFO';
source load_departments.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING employees' as 'INFO';
source load_employees.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING dept_emp' as 'INFO';
source load_dept_emp.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING dept_manager' as 'INFO';
source load_dept_manager.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING titles' as 'INFO';
source load_titles.dump ;
SELECT 'LOADING salaries' as 'INFO';
source load_salaries1.dump ;
source load_salaries2.dump ;
source load_salaries3.dump ;

source show_elapsed.sql ;
```

Comment: `source load_departments.sql` Try saving files as .sql

Comment: no it didn't work @ascii_walker

Answer (score 3):

The `source` keyword is only supported by the command line client, not MySQL Workbench (it's not a MySQL keyword). Instead load the files mentioned in the `source` commands manually into MySQL Workbench and run them there.

Alternatively, you can use the command line client as described by the readme of the employees test data github project (https://github.com/datacharmer/test_db):

```
mysql < employees.sql
```